# Count ID numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to count the number of unique operatingSystemIds

See my case :

Table : computers

```
+--------------+-------------------+
| name         | operatingSystemId |
+--------------+-------------------+
|ComputerName01|    1              |
+--------------+-------------------+
|ComputerName02|    2              |
+--------------+-------------------+
|ComputerName03|    2              |
+--------------+-------------------+
|ComputerName04|    2              |
+--------------+-------------------+
```

OperatingSystemId refers to another table listing the operating systems

Table : operatingsystems

```
+--------------+--------------------------------+
| id           | name                           |
+--------------+--------------------------------+
|1             |Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise  |
+--------------+--------------------------------+
|2             |Microsoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise|
+--------------+--------------------------------+
```

I'like to count from computers table, the number of unique operatingSystemIds to get :

1: 1
2: 3

or

Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise : 1
Microsoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise : 3

Sorry, this topic has certainly been treated many times, but i'm a newbie with SQL.

I already tried by myself to apply few examples I found, but without any success.

I thank you in advance for your help.

Jay.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do a left join

```
SELECT o.`name` , COUNT(o.id) `count`  FROM 
computers c
LEFT JOIN operatingsystems o ON (c.operatingSystemId  =o.id)
GROUP BY o.id
```

### [See Working Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e17fb/1)

Comment: If you get the ID's from the operating system table, you will just return 1, it's the primary key in operating systems table. I believe you mean COUNT(c.id)

Comment: @Hituptony also see his second desired result output and there is nothing wrong using o.id because o.id is equal to operatingSystemId use some common sense   counting operatingSystemId by o.id because c.id doesnt exist

Comment: then do it! c.id does exist, in the join clause, how can you join on a column that doesnt exist? I see what you're saying but your common sense remarks are futile here. If you desire to spam the world with your SQL Fiddle, you've done a great job. You take your rep seriously!

Comment: Once again, many thanks to the community for your help, it works like a charm. And I've learned something today.

Answer (score 0):

You need a cou nt of the number of unique operating system ID's.

Operating System ID, count(*)

1                      1

2                      3

What do you need a join for? This can all be accomplished in Computers Table.

```
SELECT OperatingSystemID, count(*) from computers group by 1
```

> OperatingSystemId refers to another table listing the operating
>   systems

Right, but because the ID on this table is the primary key, these values are unique. No need to reference this table. As long as you know what each ID correlates to it's respective name in that table. However, if you did want to include the name in this query...

```
SELECT a.OperatingSystemID, b.Name, count(a.OperatingSystemID) from computers a
inner join operatingsystem b
ON a.OperatingSystemID = b.ID
```

Here, you're using the inner join exclusively to pull the name from the operating system table and nothing else. I don't think it would construe your results, but I could be wrong.